# create a virtual server under a specific subnet

Tags: ruby, api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am using softlayer's ruby API, and i am trying to create a virtual server under a specific subnet in a VLAN and i couldnt find a way of doing it.
At the moment i am using the following json:

```
 creation_hash = {
    'complexType' => 'SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest',
    'hostname' => XXX,
    'domain' => XXXX
    'datacenter' => { 'name' => @datacenter },
    'startCpus' => sl_machine_type(@params['instance_type'])['cpu'],
    'maxMemory' => sl_machine_type(@params['instance_type'])['memory'],
    'hourlyBillingFlag' => true,
    'blockDeviceTemplateGroup' => { 'globalIdentifier' => @params['image_id'] },
    'localDiskFlag' => false,
    'dedicatedAccountHostOnlyFlag' => true,
    'primaryBackendNetworkComponent' => {
      'networkVlan' => {
        'id' => @private_vlan['id']
      }
    },
    'networkComponents' => [{ 'maxSpeed' => 1000 }],
    'privateNetworkOnlyFlag' => true
  }
```

so when i choose a VLAN, it chooses a random subnet under that VLAN.
how can i specify a subnet ? i didnt find this option in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not possible to specify which subnet a server should be provisioned into.

The provisioning system will choose an IP from the VLAN's primary subnet.

The wording is a bit vague [in this article](http://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/learning/utilizing-subnets-and-ips), but it states that IPs are automatically assigned. I will get it updated to state that it is not possible to request a specific block of IPs for the primary.

Adding an IP to the server from a secondary subnet directly after provisioning could be a possible work around. This could be done with a post install script or config manager(salt, chef, etc), if automation is needed. It would also allow you to control specifically which IPs are used for each server.

Comment: Okie, 10x for the reply. can the second IP attachment  be done through the API ?

Comment: No, this would need to be done at the OS level once the server is online. The only thing we offer that would help config a secondary IP would be [post provisioning scripts](http://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/procedure/access-provisioning-scripts-screen).

Comment: Can an alternative to this could be to replace its current IP address with the enw one ? or the original IP must stay ?

Comment: It is possible to change the original IP...but honestly its a manual process and not worth the effort. The path of least resistance is secondary IPs configured on the OS, assuming that changing your app to be more flexible with IPs or use DNS is a pain.